# How to show ngx-bootstrap datepicker when manually triggering focus on input?

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I want to implement some logic when datepicker looses focus => so (blur) but! when i want to select some date from said picker it'll trigger the logic -> closing the datepicker and not registering any value change.
My approach is `(onHidden)` since it's not triggered when i use the datepicker but when i click outside,
but it only fires when the datepicker is shown.

How can I achieve to show the datepicker when i manually set the input field to focus?
Since there are no available services and/or directive types where i can trigger `.show()`.

Stackblitz semi related example:

@Edit: modified stackblitz to fit my issue better.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mp66jv)

Comment: Give a try for `[hidden]` instead of `*ngIf`? Because ngIf will completely remove the element from the DOM, so you can't have the `nativeElement` property after it appears.

Comment: That is why i have added change detection it works with my way it sets up the focus but if I add the `click()` it just not triggering the edit mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **click()** method available in the nativeElement to trigger the DatePicker. Try it, it works.

**Edit :** With a little bit of timeout you can wait until the element becomes visible to trigger the click event.

```
 toggleEditMode() {
    this.editing = !this.editing;
    setTimeout(() => {
       if(this.picker) {
         this.picker.nativeElement.focus();
         this.picker.nativeElement.click();
       }
    },100)
  }
```

Comment: I cannot really, since my datepicker is used as an inline editor, so it needs to switch states, i have detectChanges tied to it but when i use your method it's just doesn't wanna switch inbetween display & edit mode for some reason.

Comment: Edited the stackblitz to fit my problem better

Comment: I've edited my answer @AlexBene . I've checked with your stackblitz as well. It works :)

Comment: It really works, I don't like setTimeout so i've done it with rxjs `delay()`

Comment: For some reason `changeDetector.detechChanges()` not works properly when you try to chain the native functions. But i've kept that as well. Thanks for the help now it's working good.

Comment: There is no big difference between setTimeout and delay(). An accepted answer would have helped. :)

Comment: Now my input field is not registering any changes. Modified stackblitz to match the issue.
If you click on the input (since it's triggering `onHidden`) its gonna trigger save, but when i manually entera date it's not registered as a change as well...